# What is the difference between macOS Sierra 10.12.2 Update and macOS Sierra 10.12.2 Combo Update?

Tags: macos, software-update

According to [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Sierra#Releases), both pump up the version to 10.12.2, both have exactly the same changelog:

- macOS Sierra 10.12.2 [Update](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1899?locale=en_GB)
- macOS Sierra 10.12.2 [Combo Update](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1900?locale=en_GB)

The only difference I was able to see was the file size (1.94 GB vs. 2.05 GB).

AppStore seems to mention only the "standard" update, not "combo".

[image]

Can somebody explain what are the differences? Thank you.

Comment: @calum_b and this is the reason to down vote?

Comment: I didn't downvote. It was already at -1 when I flagged it as a possible dup.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the "normal" update only has the changes from 10.12.1 to 10.12.2; therefore, you need to have 10.12.1 already installed.

The combo one, OTOH, has all the changes from the last major release (10.12.0).